# JAVA FileOutputStream overwrite some last char

Tags: java, loops

I've a `FileOutputStream` and a cicle like that:

```
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("XXXX.json"));

output.print("{\"ObjectsList\": [");

for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) { 
     output.print("{"AAAA"},");
}

output.print("]}")
```

But I don't need the `char ","` before that `output.print("]}");`

How can I write at EOF-1 or EOF-2 for overwrite the last char `","`

Answer (score 2):

Stop the loop at `something.length - 1` and make a last call to print with `output.print("{ AAAA"}");`

Comment: "AAAA" its only an example last value of something must be scansioned and added cant stop at something.length - 1

Answer (score 0):

```
   String var = "";
   var = "{\"ObjectsList\": [";

    for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) { 
         var = "{"AAAA"},";
    }

    //var.substring(0, var.length()-1) => remove the last char
    output.print(var.substring(0, var.length()-1) + "]}");
```

Comment: hmm! In your "for", you can put a if to print with no "," when the element is the last. But i think the Fabio's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 output.println("{\" ObjectsList \": [");
    for(int i=0;i<something.length;i++){
        String out="{\""+i+"}";

        if(i!=something.length-1 ){
            out+=", ";
        }
        output.println(out);
    }
    output.print("]}");
```